# Mongoose - find all documents whose array property contains a given subset?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a (simplified) model based on the following schema:

```
schema = mongoose.Schema({
    foo: { type: String },
    bars: [{ type: String }]
});
model = mongoose.model ('model', schema);
```

and I want to create an API to return all documents that contain all of the 'bars' which are provided in a comma separated list.  So I have:

```
exports.findByBars = function (req, res) {
  var barsToFind = req.body.bars.split(',');
  // find the matching document
};
```

Does Mongoose provide an API for this or is there a query param I can pass to Model#find to get this functionality?  I only want a document to be returned if its bar property contains all of the values in the `barsToFind` array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are ways to structure your query to do this, the approaches are different depending on your mongodb server version. So following on from your code:

For MongoDB version 2.6 and above, use the [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator:

```
model.find({
    "bars": { "$all": barsToFind }
},
```

And though the operator does exist for previous versions, it behaves differently so you actually need to generate an [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) statement to explicitly match each entry:

```
var andBars = [];

barsToFind.forEach(function(bar) {
    andBars.push({ "bars": bar })
});

model.find({
    "$and": andBars
},
```

Both ensure that you only match documents that contain all of the entries in the array as you have specified, it's just that the syntax available to MongoDB 2.6 is a little nicer.